# Get TLS information from the client

Tags: go, tls1.2, handshake, csr

The net/http go package has a type [request](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) that defines a field TLS holding the `ConnectionState`. Although, the last statement from the description says it's ignored by the HTTP client. I also checked that while debugging and it is `nil`.

I need to get the value `TLSUnique` from that [connection state](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#ConnectionState) (or somewhere else), so that I can include it in my certificate request, aka CSR, before I can enroll/send it to the server.
The server is out of scope of my question. My concern is about the client.

Then the server receives the request and would check the signature of the CSR along with TLS-unique value, proving that the same client with whom the TLS connection has been established with, is the same who signed the CSR.

This is something that comes from the [RFC 7030 - section 3.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7030#section-3.5) (EST protocol)

**[What I'm using]**
I'm experimenting the [GlobalSign EST](https://github.com/globalsign/est) Go package, and they don't seem to include this functionality.

Their [EST-client](https://github.com/globalsign/est/blob/v1.0.6/client.go#L545) seems to create an http client for every EST operation, I thought I could change that behavior and have one client from which we send all requests.
However, since the client accepts a [RoundTripper](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#RoundTripper) interface, i can't use information of the underlying connection outside of the [implementation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it requires a small change from the [global sign EST package](https://github.com/globalsign/est/blob/v1.0.6/client.go#L545).

Like I said earlier, the current implementation creates a new http client for every EST operation (CACerts, CSRAttrs, Enroll etc.)

1- Let's have one http client for all EST operations.
2- Either way, we're gonna need to make a call to get the CA certificates before enrolling a CSR.
3- The http response to any client request exposes the field `http.Response.TLS.TLSUnique`.
4- Let the client inlcude it in the certificate request, sign it and enroll it.

I'm not sure if there are any security concerns with this when I think about the [global sign EST package](https://github.com/globalsign/est/blob/v1.0.6/client.go#L545) and why they chose to create a new http client every time.
(unless it's just examples waiting to be used according to the user's will)

Comment: though, for a more sophisticated detailed answer, refer to @kostix

Answer (score 2):

Heads-up: in the comment thread under this answer, it became clear the OP was rather after getting the "TLS unique" value while making client requests. For that, please see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77580545/720999) or the OP's solution.
I have decided to keep this very answer for reference as it showcases a useful technique.

---

Instantiate your `http.Server`, and then set its field [`ConnContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server.ConnContext) to some function which you will need to write.

That function gets called once per each new TCP connection created by a client to your server (one connection is able to serve multiple requests).
When called, it receives the `net.Conn` which is serving the client's request, so you can type-assert it as `tls.Conn`, then call `ConnectionState` on it and inspect `TLSUnique` in the returned value.

Since you probably need to make this value available to HTTP requests carried out over that connection, the arguably most sensible solution for this is to stash that thing as "a value" in the context which will be available via the `http.Request`s in the code of the handlers.

To do that, in the same callback code, you "wrap" the original `context.Context` associated with the request, and passed to the callback, with some value extracted from that `TLSUnique`, so that you can then inspect it in the HTTP handler which is to serve the request.

Something like this (untested):

```golang
srv := &http.Server{
  ConnContext: func(ctx context.Context, c net.Conn) context.Context {
    tc := c.(*tls.Conn)

    return context.WithValue(ctx, mypkg.MyKey,
      tc.ConnectionState().TLSUnique)
  },
  // other fields, if needed
}

// ... then, in HTTP request handlers:

func MyHTTPReqHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  uniq := req.Context().Value(mypkg.MyKey)
  // verify it's not nil and use
}
```

Check the [docs on `context.Context.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context.Value) to figure out how to declare `mypkg.MyKey`.

You might also need to actually copy the value of `TLSUique` at the point of its extraction–I have no idea whether that's needed.

Comment: I'm talking from an [http.client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) perspective, the server is out of my scope.

Comment: @MoBe, I then recommend to reformulate the question to make that surely clear, as it wasn't for me (and the upvotes on my answer suggest I'm not alone with this confusion).

Comment: @MoBe, back to your question: do you really need `net/http` then? Can't you do `tls.Dial` and inspect the returned `*tls.Conn`? If you need to use the obtained connection to immediately make an HTTP request on it, then the approach is basically similar to that presented in my answer. But before I would spend my time once again providing a more informative answer, I'd prefer to wait for an acknowledgement.

Comment: Well the point was to leverage the features of the libraries as much as possible instead of creating my EST client from scratch. And before getting into any deep custom code, I would like to know if maybe there is something I missed, or a small change that can be added to the existing code. Or maybe it's just not the right library.

Comment: @MoBe, it should be possible to do by leveraging the libs (if in a somewhat non-obvious way), but the question still stands: do I understand correctly that you would like to do an HTTP request to a server, and be able to have access to the server's "TLS unique" data it has presented while the client were making its TLS connection to carry out the request being discussed–somewhere close to the point where the request is about to be constructed or sent out?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your concern. The `TLSUnique` is computed during the handshake, therefore, the http request from the client should have the same `TLSUnique` as the server's response. And thanks to you, I think I got the answer, I just tested it :) Basically, I changed the code to have one http client from which I send all EST operations. Since I get the TLS value from a 1st response, I can include it in my CSR that would be sent in my next request.

Comment: @MoBe, oh, that's _almost_ there, but there are caveats. I'll try to describe them.

Comment: @MoBe, well, I've provided a generic implementation. I don't think you're going to use it, but I find it interesting from the standpoint of what you can do with `net/http` ;-)

Comment: [1/2] @MoBe, re "one (separate) `http.Client` for each request"–I just have no idea what is your end goal to tell whether this approach is good or bad. Some insight: HTTP supports so-called "keepalives" since forever; the basic idea is that for a typical HTML page of the 90s and 00s, a client's browser would fetch the HTML, parse it and then quickly ask for images and other stuff linked from there–in order to render the complete thing. Using a separate TCP connection for that, given that most assets were served by the same server, was woefully ineffective, so they made it possible to clients…

Comment: [2/2] to say "please keep this conn open (for N seconds)", and that allowed to reuse the same single TCP conn to fetch a complete web page. `net/http` supports this naturally, and you need to specifically tinker to inhibit this behavior. Most of the time, it's super good, but now think what happens if you send two or more CSR requests over _the same_ connection? Is it OK they all will have the same "TLS unique" thing? I have no idea ;-) If yes, it's OK, then my approach is more flexible _for the general case_ – simply because it works transparently, no matter how underlying TCP works.

Comment: OK, [3/2] ;-) It may also turn out, that you actually _must_ get a unique "TLS unique" thing for each CSR. In such case, you should write your code in a way to make it absolutely _explicit._ Creating a single custom http.Client for each request is a rather common mistake of those new to Go, but it could as well be intended–I cannot say. If I were to write that code, I'd first try to understand actual requirements for those CSRs w.r.t that "TLS unique" things.

Comment: [1/2] You are awesome you know ?? Thank you for the history lessson on http. I'm not sure i have some end goal, it's just ... how to say, hmm, i found out that each new `http client` would result in a different `TLS unique`, and I had no way to retrieve that information while sending that CSR, unless I get hold of the `tls.Conn`, which I don't. And it made me wonder, why, why a new http client per EST operation.

Comment: [2/2] The generic solution you shared is making use of `callbacks` and `roundtripper`, clearly way more effective than mine because, everything is done while sending the CSR, like I wouldn't depend on any other  "dummy "request/response to fetch that TLS value first  so it can be then included in my CSR. But for simplicity, at least to have something I can start with, i'll stick with the one http client approach that would handle all EST operations ...

Comment: [3/2] :) ... but, I need to explore what happens when that connection gets idle, or if the server did not keep it alive. I mean, if the server did not keep it alive and the client sends a new request ... if a new connection gets created then it's no big deal as long as the server and client are always exchanging the same TLS unique value that is included in that particular CSR. And i don't think it's an issue if I send different CSRs using the same  TLS unique, as the purpose of it is just to make sure the CSR comes from the client with whom the TLS communication has been established with.

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on the comment thread under my other answer, here's how I would go about implementing the client side:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptrace"
)

type csrParams struct{}

type csrLazyBody struct {
    ctx    context.Context
    params csrParams

    constructed bool
    data        bytes.Buffer
}

func newCSRLazyBody(ctx context.Context, params csrParams) *csrLazyBody {
    return &csrLazyBody{
        ctx:    ctx,
        params: params,
    }
}

func (b *csrLazyBody) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    if !b.constructed {
        if err := b.construct(); err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }

        b.constructed = true
    }

    return b.data.Read(p)
}

func (b *csrLazyBody) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func (b *csrLazyBody) construct() error {
    switch uniqPtr := b.ctx.Value(tlsUniqKey).(type) {
    case nil:
        return errors.New("missing TLS unique value")
    case *[]byte:
        _, err := b.data.Write(*uniqPtr)
        return err
    default:
        panic("cannot happen")
    }
}

var _ io.ReadCloser = &csrLazyBody{}

type tlsUniqKeyType int

const tlsUniqKey = tlsUniqKeyType(0)

func newCSR(method, url string, params csrParams) (*http.Request, error) {
    uniqPtr := new([]byte)

    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(),
        tlsUniqKey, uniqPtr)

    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: func(connInfo httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
            conn := connInfo.Conn

            tc, ok := conn.(*tls.Conn)
            if !ok {
                return
            }

            uniq := tc.ConnectionState().TLSUnique

            *uniqPtr = uniq
        },
    }

    return http.NewRequestWithContext(
        httptrace.WithClientTrace(ctx, trace),
        method, url, newCSRLazyBody(ctx, params))
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    req, err := newCSR("GET", "https://csa.acme.com/api/enroll", csrParams{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

Key points:

- The function to create HTTP requests transporting CSRs to the enrollment service (I assume that's what needed), `newCSR`, creates a new `http.Request` which:

  - Is armed with a `context.Context` which:

    - Has a special "tracing" facility attached to it (see below).
    - Carries a "value" which is a pointer to a slice to contain the "TLS unique" value to be attached.
  - Contains the request body in the form of a variabe of a special type
    which initializes itself once the `Read` method is called on it for the first time.

    This variabe shares the `context.Context` with the HTTP tracer.
- The HTTP tracer's "got conn" callback is called when an `http.Transport` in use *obtains* a connection to carry out the request being traced *by any means.* This includes new connections or connections pulled from the pool of idle (reused) connections.

  If the connection is a `tls.Conn`, the callback's code extracts the "TLS unique" value from it and saves it to the variable a pointer to which is stashed in the context.
- Some time later the `http.Transport` which round-trips the request begins to read the request's body, and that's where the "lazy body construction" kicks in: it reads the pointer to the variable containing the "TLS unique" data obtained by the tracer and uses it to construct the actual CSR data, which is then read "the normal way".

---

The code is convoluted, but on the flipside it works with with any settings of the underlying `http.Transport`—with connection pooling being the major point of interest.

Of course, if you precisely know the requirements for your setup, this approach can easily be an overkill. For instance, if you know *or require* that no pooling should ever be used, it's possible to go an easier route, say:

- Use the `tls` package directly to create a `tls.Conn`, save it somewhere, and also save the "TLS unique" data extracted from it.
- Use a custom `http.Transport` which:

  - Has its `DialTLSWithContext` field set to a callback which merely
    returns that saved connection.
  - Has HTTP keepalives and idle connections disabled.
  - Maybe is wrapped in an `http.RoundTripper` which ensures only a single `RoundTrip` call is active at any given time.

Comment: Well I had a first thought of implementing a new `http.RoundTripper` where Roundtrip would basically do the job (get the TLSunique from `pconn`), include it in the CSR and sign it. Then I read that `RoundTrip()` should not modify the request. That's just part of your answer. I'll take my time to read the piece of code you suggested, there are definitely some nice stuff in there. But you haven't told me yet :) what is the caveats I might have if I followed my new answer? I'm actually intrigued because, I'm also wondering why GlobalSign package had to create one http client per EST operation.